# How do you disable all conventions in AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

Is it possible to disable all convention based mappings in AutoMapper?  I'd like to explicitly define all mappings instead of having AutoMapper make any assumptions based on property names.

I've seen the suggestion of using `.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Ignore())`, but that won't work because that kills inherited maps from `Include<>()`.

Comment: Why are you using AutoMapper if you're gong to explicitly map all properties?

Comment: The API is simple, flexible, and powerful.  Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: The rationale behind AuoMapper is that it maps fields for you automatically. If you explicitly map all fields then you loose all the magic and gain an extra dependency and possibly slower performance.

Comment: I'd also like a way to disable all conventions. Automapper is a great tool for organizing mapping code and translating whole collections at a time. However, the conventions hocus-pocus has caused too many bugs when one side of the mapping has a renamed member. If we can't turn off conventions, can you recommend a similar tool?